# Validate int value with regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to validate that input only allow maximum value: 2,147,483,647. But it's not validate at all. What is wrong in there regular expression.

```
<input
    pattern="^(([1-9][0-9]{1,9})|([2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8]{10}))$" 
    required type="number" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Regex really is inappropriate for this task. Can't you use html5's input [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-max) attribute?

Comment: ya, but i just try to learn on regex, can i validate it with regex?

Comment: Yes, but it sucks, you'll have as much `|` as there are digits in your number and it will be very inefficient. Part of learning how to use a tool is learning when not to use it ;)

Comment: ok, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Btw when you think you're sufficiently at ease with regexes you can try your skills [here](https://regex.alf.nu/). It starts easy but quickly goes on hacky stuff that'll make you scratch your head for hours

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex may be a poor solution choice for what you are seeking.  That said, below is what I believe to be a correct regex for what you are seeking to do:

```
^(0*(
    [1-9][0-9]{1,9})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6]4[0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3]6[0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8]3[0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4]8[0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7]4[0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4]7[0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1]4[0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2]1[0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   (2[0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-4][0-8])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-6][0-3][0-9])|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-3][0-5][0-9]{2})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-8][0-2][0-9]{3})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-4][0-7][0-9]{4})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-7][0-3][0-9]{5})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-4][0-6][0-9]{6})|
   ([1-2][0-1][0-3][0-9]{7})|
   ([1-2]0[0-9]{8})|
   (1[0-9]{9})
)$
```

The whitespace and newlines are only for clarity and are not part of the regex.  I do not guarantee its correctness though I think it is.  You can try this out at a place like [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

As you can see this is complex and should probably be generated by a program instead of a human.

The ugliness of the answer hints that it is a poor choice of solution.